# Entity Framework not loading child entities correctly

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a data model like this:

Article

```
     *Id     | int
    ...      |
```

Activity

```
     *ArticleId    | int
     *ActivityType | nvarchar(50)
     *AccountId    | nvarchar(50)
     ...           |
```

In the above, star (`*`) columns are the primary key and `ArticleId` is foreign key of article id.

I use Entity Framework 6 database first. When I run below code results is not equal most of the time! the result is repeatable.

Query A:

```
var aCount1 = db.Article.Include("Activity")
                .First(x => x.Id == 1).Activity.Count;
```

Query B:

```
var aCount2 = db.Activity.First(x => x.ArticleId == 1).Count();
```

I used lazy loading and eager loading and nothing changed.

Entity Framework queries:

Query A:

```
    SELECT 
        [Extent1].[ActivityType] AS [ActivityType], 
        [Extent1].[AccountId] AS [AccountId], 
        [Extent1].[ArticleId] AS [ArticleId]
    FROM 
        [dbo].[Activity] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE 
        [Extent1].[ArticleId] = @EntityKeyValue1
```

Query B:

```
    SELECT 
        [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
             COUNT(1) AS [A1]
         FROM 
             [dbo].[Activity] AS [Extent1]
         WHERE 
             ([Extent1].[ArticleId] = @p__linq__0))  AS [GroupBy1]
```

When I execute above queries from SSMS results is same, but fetched objects on EF is not true.

Comment: Create a short, complete repro of this issue.  You'll probably discover the issue.  If not, post it here.

Comment: I am unclear what behaviour you are experiencing, what you are expecting, and what is the difference between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your .edmx file with "open with"=>"automatic editor selector" to be sure that all your Key columns (in your case:ArticleId,ActivityType,AccountId) exist in the key section of the related entity. That way you could be sure that there is no problem with your model, then we can get deeper into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Query B must be changed to

```
Query B) var aCount2 = db.Activity.Where(x=>x.ArticleId == 1).Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have two databases because of technical constraints. On local DB, ArticleId was not part of primary key but it's ok on primary DB. I think EF used primary key for level one caching, so when I repeated queries with different ArticleId on current session, it might return wrong result.